# is there a way to generate input fields in ascx from sharepoint 2010 list

Tags: sharepoint

I'm developing a custom aspx form for a SharePoint list in Visual Studio, basically to add a new item to the list (that's a business requirement).

I'm wondering if there's a way to generate input controls from the list in design time just like we used to do from a database in ASP.NET.

Comment: This question would probably get more attention on [SharePoint StackExchange](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions)

Comment: Would you like to be able to use the user control internally in SharePoint or would you like to be able to use it externally as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered T4, that's exactly what I'm looking for,,, I used it to generate input controls in design time... I faced some problems accessing SharePoint from T4 templates but were resolved using The Client Object model :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing a straight match from the SP List to web form take a look at the [SharePoint Form Generator](http://sfg.codeplex.com/) web part

Just add the web part to the page and identify which list to build a form for.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, yes there is a way to generate the fields. What you are looking for is the Sharepoint FormField class in the webccontrols namespace.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.formfield.aspx

Here is an article explaining the entire field controls heirarchy for sharepoint. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543321.aspx

Generally this is used inside an ASCX control, let me know if you need any more explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the useful links, but that didn't answer my actual question. I mean while designing the user control instead of doing it by hand having some tool generate the input fields for me in design time.

Comment: ahh okay I understand the question now.